# How can I open a PWA in the real Safari on iOS 12.2+?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I need to be able to use the camera in my PWA, so with the limitations in iOS, I can't really use the normal PWA.

My question is - can I create a PWA that simply loads my website in Safari?  I understand that I will get the url bar and all the nastiness, but at least it would give me an icon on the home screen.

However, according to [this article](https://medium.com/@firt/pwas-on-ios-12-2-beta-the-good-the-bad-and-the-not-sure-yet-if-good-a37b6fa6afbf):

"Up to iOS 12.1, every link pointing to a destination outside of the manifest’s scope opens in Safari by default. From iOS 12.2 beta 1, an In-app browser is used. Therefore, all your links now open within your own app’s scope and they have a “Done” button to go back to your app. Every navigation that you make on that window will happen there. Back gesture is enabled on this browser (dragging from the edge to the right)."

How do I open Safari from a PWA in iOS 12.2+?